# Subsets of an equivalence relation- terminology question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an increasing sequence of sets and let, for any $n\in\mathbb N$, $R_n$ be a relation on $A_n$ (i.e. a subset of $A_n\times A_n$, such that the following hold

1. For any $n\in\mathbb N$, the relation $R_n$ is reflexive and symmetric on $A_n$,
2. For any $n\le m\le k$, given $a_n\in A_n$, $a_m\in A_m$ and $a_k\in A_k$, such that $a_n R_m a_m$ and $a_m R_k a_k$, there exists some $l\ge k$ such that $a_n R_l a_k$.

That is to say, the relations $R_n$ themselves are not necessarily equivalence relations, but their union is an equivalence on $A_n$.

I was wondering if such a phenomenon has a commonly used name (e.g. pre-equivalence or graded equivalence relation). I came upon a sequence of relations of this sort recently, and would rather use the commonly used name, if such exists.

Thank you!

Comment: To be precise, this is *stronger* than "the union is an equivalence relation"

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was just trying to explain what the two items imply, I didn't mean to say that the two are equivalent. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I suppose you mean (in the end of point 2.) "... such that $a_n R_l a_k$". As it is, this is an obvious sentence (just pick $l=k$).

Comment: Oh, yes, thank you@amrsa.